# How to use Count result in the Where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server query which `COUNT`s based on the values of `id` columns.

Like this:

```
SELECT 
    [id], 
    COUNT(*) AS IdCount,   
FROM  
    myTable  
WHERE
    DATEDIFF(day, [Time], GETDATE()) < 30   
GROUP BY 
    [id]
```

I want to add the value of the `COUNT` result in the `WHERE` condition. How can I do that?

```
SELECT 
    [id],
    COUNT(*) AS IdCount,
    RANK() OVER (ORDER BY IdCount) CountRank
FROM  
    myTable
WHERE
    DATEDIFF(day, [Time], GETDATE()) < 30 
    AND {Count values is > 100}
GROUP BY 
    [id]
```

Comment: It's unclear what exactly you want to do. Could you please provide some sample input and expected outcome as tables?

Comment: Side note: it is more efficient to do `WHERE Time >= DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE())` although the semantics of date boundaries are slightly different this way, so you may want `WHERE Time >= DATEADD(day, -30, CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS date) AS datetime))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL does not allow aggregate functions, such as COUNT or SUM, in the where clause. You can use a subquery or the HAVING function. You can see the [documentation for a subquery for Microsoft SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/subqueries?view=sql-server-ver16).

With the information available here, I suspect the HAVING clause might solve your problem more easily. Please see the [documentation for the HAVING clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-having-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

```
SELECT 
    [id], 
    COUNT(*) AS IdCount,   
FROM  myTable  
WHERE DATEDIFF(day,[Time],GETDATE()) < 30
GROUP BY [id]
HAVING COUNT(IdCount) > SOMENUMBER
```

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate functions can't be used in the where clause but below the group by you can add them in a having clause:

```
select id
from table
group by id
having count(*)>1
```